# Smoother Keypressed event for paddle object in pong

Tags: python, events, pygame

I'm trying to make my paddle movements smoother in my pong game. My player_paddle1 has smooth movements and will stop whenever I let go of the key. However, my other player_paddle2, which incorporates the same keypress algorithm has the other paddle, does not do so. It will keep on going even if I release the key.

```
        if game_option == "Two Player":
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    player_paddle1.direction = -1
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    player_paddle1.direction = 1

                if event.key == K_w:
                    player_paddle2.direction = -1
                elif event.key == K_s:
                    player_paddle2.direction = 1

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_UP and player_paddle1.direction == -1:
                    player_paddle1.direction = 0
                elif event.key == K_DOWN and player_paddle1.direction == 1:
                    player_paddle1.direction = 0

                if event.key == K_UP and player_paddle2.direction == -1:
                    print("The key is now up!")
                    player_paddle2.direction = 0 
                elif event.key == K_UP and player_paddle2.direction == 1:
                    player_paddle2.direction = 0
```

Also, while the up and down keys are extremely responsive, the W and S keys are not too responsive, which means, a keypressed will not immedieatly result in paddle motion. How can I fix this?

Comment: why do you check `K_UP` for second player if it uses `K_w` and `K_s`

Answer (score 0):

You check `K_UP` for second player in `KEYUP` but it has to be `K_w` and `K_s`.

Besides you don't have to check `player_paddle2.direction`

```
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                player_paddle1.direction = 0
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                player_paddle1.direction = 0

            elif event.key == K_w: # <-- there was K_UP
                print("The key is now up!")
                player_paddle2.direction = 0 
            elif event.key == K_s: # <-- there was K_UP
                player_paddle2.direction = 0
```

it can be shorter

```
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key in (K_UP, K_DOWN)
                player_paddle1.direction = 0

            elif event.key in (K_w, K_s):
                player_paddle2.direction = 0
```

BTW: you can use `elif` in some places.